# how to read the value of variable type dma_addr_t

Tags: linux-kernel, dma

`dma_alloc_coherent()` returns a pointer for storing any data. And this function takes a variable of type `dma_addr_t` and it is used for DMA operations. So I want to read this value before DMA operation starts.

Comment: You may get more useful answers if you post code you have tried and where it seems to go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In according to [DMA-API.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/DMA-API.txt) `dma_alloc_coherent()` returns address in CPU virtual space. Meanwhile `dma_handle` is the address of the same region which may be used **by the device that does actual DMA**. In case you would like to get that value just use it as an integer that can contain such value, or print it as showed below:

```
  dma_addr_t handle;
  void *cpu_addr;

  cpu_addr = dma_alloc_coherent(…, &handle, …);
  pr_info("%s: got DMA address: %pad\n", __func__, &handle);
```

Comment: I need the contents present in that dma address actually. I can read these values using mem dd 0xDMA_ADDR 0x40 command on run tlite prompt after my module is loaded.  Initially tried to print these values using C code but no luck.

Comment: `cpu_addr` is the address on CPU side.